# Copy URL, Remove the '/' and '.php' and paste remaining in place of Column in Php for MySQLdb

Tags: php, mysql

If my site is:

www.abc.com/efg.php

then how can I automatically paste only efg in place of the column name (which is firstnamee in this one)

Here is the Coding:

```
mysql_select_db("blahblah_abcdefgh") or die(mysql_error());  

$data = mysql_query("SELECT firstnamee FROM qwerty")  or die(mysql_error());  

$result=mysql_result($data);
echo $result;
?>
```

Thanks in advance

One more thing efg is an existing column in my DB

Comment: So you want to grab the file name as column name for your query? If yes then you almost kill your own site, because this will expand to a SQL injection party

Comment: Are you sure you want to change the column name and not the column value?

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks for the info. Is there any alternative that I can use?

Comment: Well I would need to know what you goal is with this code to be able to help you

Comment: @Rizier123 just creating a database for my business to receive the details of my products just by entering the i.d no. in url (like 'efg' is the product id)

Comment: You prolly want to use URL rewriting then for this and not a single file for each table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If my site is:
>
> www.abc.com/efg.php

Then `efg` is

```
$value = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
```

Use it as you please :) Cause i'm not going to add it to your injection prone query :)

Comment: Tried. But not working in the coding

Comment: Can we see your updated code?